# how to create duplicate input element with unique name attribute in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I would like to create a duplicate input element like the following

```
<input
  type="text"
  className="form-control mb-3"
  id="whatweoffer"
  name="whatweoffer"
  value={this.state.whatweoffer}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  placeholder="what we offer"
  required
/>;
```

But it should have a different name attribute and the value must be used to set the state

```
handleChange = e => {
  this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};
```

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of objects that will contain the properties of the inputs, and set the same to state.

```
this.state = {
  inputs: [
    {
      name: 'whatweoffer_name',
      value: 'whatweoffer_value',
      placeholder: 'whatweoffer_placeholder'
    },
    {
      name: 'whatweoffer_2_name',
      value: 'whatweoffer_2_value',
      placeholder: 'whatweoffer_2_placeholder'
    }
  ]
}
```

And utilize the same in the `render()`:

```
render() {
  return(

    {this.state.inputs.map(input => (
      <input
      type="text"
      className="form-control mb-3"
      id={input.name}
      name={input.name}
      value={input.value}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      placeholder={input.placeholder}
      required
    />;
    ))}

  )
}
```

Then your `handleChange` becomes so:

```
handleChange = e => {
  // Fetch the name and value of the input that fired the method
  const {name, value} = e.target 

  this.setState(prevState => {
    // Take copy of the input list
    let {inputs} = prevState
    // Find the index of the object in the input list to be updated
    const inputIndex = inputs.findIndex(input => input.name === name)
    // Update the item
    inputs[inputIndex].value = value

    return { inputs }
  });
};
```